# SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS) Service cannot start. It's referring to a file that doesn't exist

Tags: windows, sql-server, sql, visual-studio-2010

I'm learning how to create an application in Visual Studio and following a tutorial to create a service-based database. When I try to add the new item (service-based db) in Visual Studio, I got the following error:

[image]

After doing some research, I found that the "SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS)" service is stopped. I suppose that if I start the service, everything would be ok but I received this error instead:

[image]

Following the suggestion in the second error message, I look for the info in Event Viewer and I found a few error messages associated with the failed service start:

> FCB::Open failed: Could not open file e:\sql10_main_t\sql\mkmastr\databases\objfre\i386\MSDBData.mdf for file number 1.  OS error: 3(failed to retrieve text for this error. Reason: 15105).
>
> FCB::Open failed: Could not open file e:\sql10_main_t\sql\mkmastr\databases\objfre\i386\model.mdf for file number 1.  OS error: 3(failed to retrieve text for this error. Reason: 15100).
>
> FileMgr::StartLogFiles: Operating system error 2(failed to retrieve text for this error. Reason: 15105) occurred while creating or opening file 'e:\sql10_main_t\sql\mkmastr\databases\objfre\i386\modellog.ldf'. Diagnose and correct the operating system error, and retry the operation.

At this point, I don't know what to do because the directory `e:\sql10_main_t\sql....`  doesn't exist! My E:\ drive is labelled as `System Reserved` and I have un-tick the `Hide protected operating system file (Recommended)` in File Explorer options to show all the hidden folders inside to confirm that this directory doesn't exist.

I can re-install the SQL Server but I want to know how do I fix this issue without re-installing? Or maybe there are something that I'm missing?

Comment: Is it possible that your drivers changed letter and there used to be a different driver with the letter **E:** assigned to it? What's the SQL Server version?

Comment: @Ronaldo , its SQL server 2008. I don't remember changing the drive letter of System Reserved and I don't remember installing the SQL server individually, I assume that it was installed together with the Visual Studio.. which I only install a couple of months ago. I'm looking in other drives whether this directory exists but so far I haven't found it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try to rebuild the system databases running the following on a `CMD` prompt:

1. Change directories to the location of the `setup.exe` file. The default location on your computer should be something like `C:\Program
   Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\SQLServer2008`.
2. Run `Setup /QUIET /ACTION=REBUILDDATABASE /INSTANCENAME=SQLEXPRESS /SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS=YourAccountsHere /SAPWD=YourSaLoginPassword`

Check the [Rebuild System Databases](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/rebuild-system-databases?view=sql-server-ver15#RebuildProcedure) documentation to understand the options.

Also you might check these [social msdn](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/393ed03b-a860-4bba-8331-36ebe318023c/unable-to-open-the-physical-file?forum=sqlexpress) and [sqlservercentral](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/rebuilding-master-database) posts related to your problem. It won't reinstall SQL Server, instead it will recreate the system databases with the broken references to the nonexistent path shown on the error message.